# Drawing two surfaces which intersect at a point or made a surface

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

Is it possible to draw a similar kind of diagram in Latex or in other software? [image]  This picture is there in  Differential topology by Guillemin and Pollack. I need to give a similar sort of pictures for the tutorial. I am aware of the basics of Tikz plot.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi pi. Could you please show what you have tried so far?

Comment: @JouleV I have done some attempts using https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158585/draw-3d-intersecting-surfaces
As I am not aware of these kinds of drawing in Tikz I am trying to edit the code.

Comment: I don't think there is any software in TeX's packages to make this easy, but I would suggest you look at asymptote (http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/) or at blender (https://www.blender.org/), both of which would require significant time for you to learn how to use them.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay Okay, thanks. I will learn one of them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a`just-do-it-for-me` question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is certainly not a complete answer but the purpose is to make it easier to draw stretches of plots, which then can be patched together like e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/488869/121799). If you use asymptote, such patching is not necessary, but with Ti*k*Z and other means that do not have a 3d engine it is.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\tikzset{3d stuff/.is family,
3d stuff/.cd,
parse domain/.code args={#1:#2}{\def\xmin{#1}\def\xmax{#2}},
surface segment/.is family,
surface segment/.cd,
x/.initial=0:1, 
y/.initial=0:1,
function/.initial=f,
plane/.initial=0
}
\tikzset{set surface segment/.code=\tikzset{3d stuff/surface segment/.cd,#1},
surface stretch/.style={/utils/exec=
\pgfkeys{/tikz/3d stuff/parse domain/.expanded=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d stuff/surface segment/y}}
\edef\ymin{\xmin}
\edef\ymax{\xmax}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/3d stuff/parse domain/.expanded=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d stuff/surface segment/x}},
insert path={%
\ifcase\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d stuff/surface segment/plane} %xy
plot[variable=\x,smooth,domain=\xmin:\xmax] 
 (\x,\ymin,{#1(\x,\ymin)})
-- plot[variable=\y,smooth,domain=\ymin:\ymax] 
 (\xmax,\y,{#1(\xmax,\y)})
--plot[variable=\x,smooth,domain=\xmax:\xmin] 
 (\x,\ymax,{#1(\x,\ymax)})
-- plot[variable=\y,smooth,domain=\ymax:\ymin] 
 (\xmin,\y,{#1(\xmin,\y)})
--cycle
\or%xz
plot[variable=\x,smooth,domain=\xmin:\xmax] 
 (\x,{#1(\x,\ymin)},\ymin)
-- plot[variable=\y,smooth,domain=\ymin:\ymax] 
 (\xmax,{#1(\xmax,\y)},\y)
--plot[variable=\x,smooth,domain=\xmax:\xmin] 
 (\x,{#1(\x,\ymax)},\ymax)
-- plot[variable=\y,smooth,domain=\ymax:\ymin] 
 (\xmin,{#1(\xmin,\y)},\y)
--cycle
\or%yz
plot[variable=\x,smooth,domain=\xmin:\xmax] 
 ({#1(\x,\ymin)},\x,\ymin)
-- plot[variable=\y,smooth,domain=\ymin:\ymax] 
 ({#1(\xmax,\y)},\xmax,\y)
--plot[variable=\x,smooth,domain=\xmax:\xmin] 
 ({#1(\x,\ymax)},\x,\ymax)
-- plot[variable=\y,smooth,domain=\ymax:\ymin] 
 ({#1(\xmin,\y)},\xmin,\y)
--cycle
\fi
}}}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{150}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,declare function={%
 f(\x,\y)=0.3*sin(deg(\x);
 g(\x,\y)=-3*sin(deg(2.2*\x);}]
 \draw[set surface segment={x=-pi:0,y=0:2},surface stretch=f];
 \draw[set surface segment={x=0:0.2*pi,y=0:2},surface stretch=g];
 \draw[fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,set surface segment={x=0:pi,y=0:2},surface stretch=f];
 \draw[fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,set surface segment={x=-0.2*pi:0,y=0:2},surface stretch=g];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]