# How to start these images in TIKZ? 3D integral

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I need to make these two images in TIKZ, the image on the left I got, it's ready.
Now I need to remove the solid below this function, I'm not sure where to begin.
I want to show with the image of the left the integral under the surface and in the image of the right which volume is being calculated.

Comment: Consider accepting the provided answer since it seems to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the solid is as simple as removing the code that produces it from [this code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/488869/121799).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,>=stealth,declare function={%
pfft(\x)=pi+0.3*sin(deg(\x));}]
 \draw[->] (0,0,0) coordinate (O) -- (5,0,0) coordinate(X) node[pos=1.1]{$x$};
 \draw[->] (O) -- (0,5,0) node[pos=1.1]{$y$};
 \draw[->] (O) -- (0,0,5) node[pos=1.1]{$z$};
 \path[opacity=0.3,left color=blue,right color=blue,middle color=blue!20,shading
  angle=72]
   plot[variable=\x,domain=0:1.1*pi,smooth] (3,\x,{pfft(2*\x)}) --
   plot[variable=\x,domain=1.1*pi:0,smooth] (0,\x,{pfft(2*\x)}) -- cycle;
 \path[opacity=0.3,left color=blue,right color=blue,middle color=blue!20,shading
  angle=72]
   plot[variable=\x,domain=1.1*pi:2.2*pi,smooth] (3,\x,{pfft(2*\x)}) --
   plot[variable=\x,domain=2.2*pi:1.1*pi,smooth] (0,\x,{pfft(2*\x)}) -- cycle;
 \draw plot[variable=\x,domain=0:2.2*pi,smooth] (3,\x,{pfft(2*\x)}) --
 plot[variable=\x,domain=2.2*pi:0,smooth] (0,\x,{pfft(2*\x)}) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]